# selecting statistical test

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, experiment-design, group-differences

I wish to analyse data regarding physical activity levels of a population (unaware yet if it will be parametric or non parametric) at baseline, week 12 and follow up at three months. My research proposes to be an RCT and my aim is to detect if there is a significant difference between the intervention group and the control group at these three time points. Can anyone explain what tests I would be best off using? 
Should I not use Mann Whitney U test as I am evaluating differences at three time points? Is this where Anova should be used?

Any help would be absolutely amazing as I'm very stressed and have limited experience with statistics! simple explanation needed !! thank you